# Laravel: Querying if a relationship exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have a model `Foo` that contains a `hasMany` relationship to `Bar`.

I have a query similar to the following:

```
$r = Foo::with(['bar' => function($query) {
    $query->where('someProp', '=', 10);
})->get()
```

However, I want to only return the `Foo` object if item has a `Bar` object that satisfies the query.

I'm aware that you can do something like this:

```
$r = Foo::has('bar')
    ->with(['bar' => function($query) {
        $query->where('someProp', '=', 10);
    })->get();
```

But that checks if any `bar` items exists. Not if a `bar` item exists with `someProp = 10`

The closest I have got to a solution is this:

```
$r = Foo::has('bar')
    ->whereHas('bar', function ($query) {
         $query->where('someProp', '=', 10);
    })
    ->with(['bar' => function($query) {
        $query->where('someProp', '=', 10);
    })->get();
```

But it's clearly not a very nice solution and is probably quite inefficient as I am repeating queries.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If the condition is a fix one, you could define another relationship in Foo like this

```
public function bar_fix()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bar::class)->where('someProp', 10);
}
```

And then use this relationship in the query:

```
$r = Foo::has('bar_fix')->with('bar_fix')->get();
```

however, this is just usefull if the condition is fix..